# Count the number of Yearly duplicates in a time index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I have a dataframe which has daily observation from 2000 to 2020. The dataframe looks like the table below. In "Label" columns there are only three labels "a", "b" and "c".

| Date | Label |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 | a |
| 2000-01-01 | b |
| 2000-01-01 | b |
| 2000-01-01 | c |
| 2000-01-01 | a |
| ... | ... |
| 2020-12-30 | c |

How can I count the repeat of "a", "b" and "c" separately on annual basis. For example, I'm looking for following table as result for each of "a", "b" and "c":

| Year | number of "a" repeats |
| --- | --- |
| 2000 | 5 |
| 2001 | 10 |
| 2002 | 13 |
| 2003 | 20 |
| ... | ... |
| 2020 | 1 |

Comment: Convert the date to year only, then use `value_counts` on year and label

Comment: Or use `pd.crosstab(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year, df['Label'])`